# Reading standard(console) input from file and printing output to other file

Tags: java, file-io

What I'm trying to do is to make my program read input test-cases from a file instead of standard console input and write back the output to another file.
Here comes the problem into play, if I'm trying to give input using file it is showing ***java.lang.NullPointerException***, but on other hand giving correct output if I'm trying to give custom standard input(using cmd) and printing output to a file.

Here is my sample program:

```
public class Roman
{
static private final String INPUT = "Q4.in";  
static private final String OUTPUT = "Q4.out";  

  // open I/O files  


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    FileInputStream instream = null;  
  PrintStream outstream = null;  

  try {  
      instream = new FileInputStream(INPUT);  
      outstream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT));  
      System.setIn(instream);  
      System.setOut(outstream);  
  } catch (Exception e) {  
      System.err.println("Error Occurred.");  
  }  
    int i;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    int T=sc.nextInt();

    Num2Rom[] tc=new Num2Rom[T];

    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
    {  tc[i]=new Num2Rom();  }

    System.out.println(T+"\n");

    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
    {  tc[i].display(i+1);  }
  }
}
```

and

```
ArrayList<String> wordList;

Num2Rom()
{ 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(sc.hasNext()){
    String numeral = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("print"+numeral);
    numeral = numeral.toUpperCase();

    String[] words = numeral.split(" ");
    wordList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(words));  } 
}
```

The input is formatted as:

```
2
Eight
Twenty
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java command line arguements to give input to the program.

```
class A{  
public static void main(String args[]){  

for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)  
System.out.println(args[i]);  

}  
}
```

do convert the arguments to the desired type,as arguments are received in the string format.

such as if you want an integere you can convert using

```
int value=Integer.parseInt($args[0]);
```